# Version of OCI8 and Oracle Instant Client

Tags: php, oracle, apache, redhat, oci8

I've got:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
PHP 5.4.16 
Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Oracle12c DataBase

What version of OCI8 and Oracle Instant Client should I use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 use the latest PHP OCI8 2.0 you can.  Currently the most recent is 2.0.12 on https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8.  Use 'pecl install oci8-2.0.12' to install it.

If your database is on a remote machine use Instant Client 12.2.  Oracle Database supports client-to-server library version interoperability so you can use older or new Oracle client versions, if necessary.  The latest client (12.2) has some improvements - of course!

If your database is on the same machine that PHP is on, you don't need Instant Client.